# Firefox and Safari Margins

Tags: css, firefox, safari, margins

How do i get my margins and padding to display correctly across both firefox and safari? What is the proper hack, generally speaking?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a CSS reset, this resets all elements to a default value and thus will display the same in all browsers, including internet explorer.

More info here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

here is the way i do it, it removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default styling of HTML elements. first i reset the stylesheet using [yui reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/):

```
/* RESET
---------------------------
Yahoo Reset
version: 3.3.0
build: 3167
*/
html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
```

and then i use [yahoo css](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/base/) base to declare style for common HTML elements:

```
/* BASE 
--------------------------------------
Yahoo Base
version: 3.3.0
build: 3167
*/

h1,h2,h3{margin:1em 0;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,strong{font-weight:bold; color:#333}abbr,acronym{border-bottom:1px dotted #000;cursor:help;}em{font-style:italic;}blockquote,ol,dl{margin:1em;}ol,dl{margin-left:2em;}ol li{list-style:decimal outside;}dl dd{margin-left:1em;}th{font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}caption{margin-bottom:.5em;text-align:center;}fieldset,table,pre{margin-bottom:1em;}
```

Comment: I have reset my css, but things are still off in firefox for 1 of my elements.  I now need to do it specifically to one rule...1 set of instructions for safari, the other for firefox. How do i do a margin hack for both browsers?